# Is it necessary to select font styling from google fonts?

Tags: html, css, google-font-api

I often use Google Fonts for my web, Is it necessary to select font weights and then add like this `fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Crimson+Text:400,700"` or I can just select regular one `family=Crimson+Text:400"` and change it to bold/semi-bold with css ?
Whats the difference ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, its necessary to specify the weights.

Take a look at the css file you included [fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Crimson+Text:400,700](https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Crimson+Text:400,700)

Here is what it contains:

```
/* latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Crimson Text';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Crimson Text Regular'), local('CrimsonText-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/crimsontext/v8/wlp2gwHKFkZgtmSR3NB0oRJfbwhT.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
}
/* latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Crimson Text';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  src: local('Crimson Text Bold'), local('CrimsonText-Bold'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/crimsontext/v8/wlppgwHKFkZgtmSR3NB0oRJX1C1GDNNQ.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
}
```

Notice in particular the lines `font-weight: 400;` and `font-weight: 700;`

These tell your browser which glyphs to use when that weight is selected, your browser cannot simply **Bold** or *italicize* your text based on weight, it needs to download and render the appropriate glyphs